# Two WearableListenerService. How can one send request only to other device?

Tags: android, synchronization, assets

please help.
I have two WearableListenerServices. The first on phone and the second on a watch. if I send asset data from wear to phone, for example:

```
PutDataMapRequest dataMap = PutDataMapRequest.create(AUDIO_PATH);
        dataMap.getDataMap().putAsset(REC_AUDIO_KEY, asset);
        dataMap.getDataMap().putLong(TIME, new Date().getTime());
        dataMap.getDataMap().putString(NAME, name);
        PutDataRequest request = dataMap.asPutDataRequest();
        Wearable.DataApi.putDataItem(mGoogleApiClient, request).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DataApi.DataItemResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(DataApi.DataItemResult dataItemResult)           {
                    if (!dataItemResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                        failRecord();
                    }else{
                        successRecord(true);
                    }
            }
        });
```

I expect that result will be from phone, but in fact response come back from itself. The problem is that on the watch executed method onDataChanged earlier then on the Phone. How can I send request only to other device?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have u cross checked the path (AUDIO_PATH) ? It should be same in onDataChanged of wearableListenerService located in phone and not to be same in onDataChanged of wearableListenerService located in Wear.

In your question you have already mentioned that u need to send request to only one side then u dont have to implement onDataChangedMethod in Sending side.

Comment: I have a function to send from the watch to the phone and there is also a function to send from the phone to the watch. Therefore, on both devices is implemented WearableListenerService.